# If there are two .cpp files in one project with the same variable declared, why linker shows no error if only one is static?

Tags: c++, syntax, static, linker, linker-errors

Let's say that we have two `.cpp` files: `main.cpp` and `another.cpp`, and they are both in one project. In `main.cpp` we create the global variable `static int foo = 10` and in `another.cpp` we create `int foo = 20`.

Now, if both of them were non-`static`, the linker would inform us about an error indicating that multiple instances of a variable are declared. But in the aforementioned example, Clion actually compiles without error.

In my understanding, both of these variables are visible in `main.cpp`, even if only the non-`static` one is visible in `another.cpp`. Why does the linker not require both of them to be `static`?

Comment: Looks like you are not familiar with what happens when you declare a `static` variable at file scope.  That variable is only known to that file.   The `foo` declared in another module is not the same as the static `foo` declared in the file, even though the names are the same.

Comment: Tactical note: CLion is a tool that sits on top of a compiler. It does none of the compiling, making it irrelevant to this question.

Comment: This question is "How does the build know main.cpp should use the locally-defined `static` `foo` rather than the `foo` in another.cpp?"

Comment: @user4581301 in which case, the question becomes, "why do you think `main.cpp` would even know about the non-static `foo` in `another.cpp` to begin with?" Unless the non-static `foo` is `extern`'ed in `main.cpp`, there is no reason for either the compiler or the linker to care about it in `main.cpp` at all.

Comment: "In my understanding, both of these variables are visible in main.cpp"  That's likely where your (mis)understanding and the compiler diverge.